# the topology of power series ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Hi, everyone.

Let $A$ be a complete DVR with uniformizer $t$, $R:=A[[X]]$. What is the natural topology of $R$ ?

Comment: The ring $R$ is complete both for the $\langle X \rangle$-adic topology and for the $\langle t, X \rangle$-adic topology. So it depends on what you want to study about $R$.

Comment: I'm sure an answer can be very quickly found at http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: The question is subtler than it appears, depending on the topology you choose its formal spectrum is completely different.

Comment: I think there is no "natural" topology, as Leo says.

Comment: A naive question: what is DVR?

Comment: discrete valuation ring I suppose, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring
